# What's the difference between `dig` and `host` when querying a specific name-server?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, host, dig

I was using this command to verify if I'd set things up correctly with a DNS provider:

```
host hostname.example.com ns1.example-nameserver.com
```

As far as I can tell, this asks `ns1.example-nameserver.com` to look up `hostname.example.com` and reports the answer. I was getting a host-not-found response so I thought I'd done it wrong. However, without specifying their name-server (thus allowing my ISP's name-server to look it up) I got the correct response (`hostname` is a `CNAME` if it matters). I couldn't fathom this so I searched around and found the `dig` command:

```
dig @ns1.example-nameserver.com hostname.example.com
```

As far as I can tell this does the same thing as the `host` command - asks a specific name-server to look up a host. I therefore conclude that they must do it differently somehow, and that caching name-servers must use the same method as `dig`.

My conclusion is either right or wrong, if it is right:

What is the difference between these two look-up methods?

If it is wrong:

What are my misunderstandings about DNS and the `host` and `dig` commands that have led me to this conclusion?

Example output:

```
$ host cardiff.tzmchapters.org ns1.livedns.co.uk
Using domain server:
Name: ns1.livedns.co.uk
Address: 213.171.192.250#53
Aliases: 

Host cardiff.tzmchapters.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ dig @ns1.livedns.co.uk cardiff.tzmchapters.org

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns1.livedns.co.uk cardiff.tzmchapters.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23620
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cardiff.tzmchapters.org.   IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cardiff.tzmchapters.org. 3600   IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     3600    IN  SOA ns1.livedns.co.uk. admin.google.com. 1354213742 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 213.171.192.250#53(213.171.192.250)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 22 23:47:05 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128
```

Comment: both commands should work the same way in this case. Can you show the complete output of each command?

Comment: Notice how both `dig` and `host` report `NXDOMAIN`. With `dig` you can see it in the header (5th non-blank line of the output) and with `host` it's more obvious. `NXDOMAIN` means the domain does not exist. Yet a `CNAME` is returned in the answer section! I do believe that's a bug in the DNS server!

Comment: So in that case, do `dig` and `host` both send the exact same query packet, get the exact same response packet (aside from any timestamps), but interpret it differently? Does `host` bail out as soon as it sees `NXDOMAIN`?

Comment: FWIW I have the exact opposite problem on a specific subdomain. Using host on this specific subdomain provides the expected record showing that this particular subdomain resolves to an expected canonical hostname. However, when using dig on this particular subdomain - I receive a response that the record does not exist. Additionally navigating to this subdomain with a browser does not work. I've tried multiple times, checking for spelling mistakes, etc. The commands are clearly NOT working in the same way.

Answer (score 21):

`host`, `dig`, and `nslookup` all share most of the same functionality. In the case you are asking about (asking a particular DNS question to a particular nameserver), `dig` and `host` (and indeed `nslookup`) behave exactly the same.

For DNS troubleshooting, `dig` is preferred because its output format is more "raw": in its output it directly shows the contents of all 4 fields in the DNS response: question, answer, authority, and additional sections (plus the flags in the header), and also it has more options. `host`, on the other hand, has a more user-friendly output format.

If you don't happen to need an option that one of the commands has and the others don't, or a piece of information that one of them outputs and the others don't, then it comes down to a matter of preference.

Comment: If they do the same thing on the network side (the actual query) how can I be getting host not found when using `host` but the correct answer when using `dig`? Even if the server is configured using a particular setting (either by choice or accident) to cause this, it must be able to differentiate the requests.

Comment: Nope! The two commands you give in your question are equivalent and they should produce the same answer! Are you sure that `dig` gave you an actual *answer* and not a record in the additional or authority section? As [Renan](http://serverfault.com/users/108127/renan) suggests, it might help to show the output.

Comment: Ok, I've added some example output. I get the same result at home and at work. When I don't specify a name server to use and my ISP handles the query, `host` works fine. Please try it yourself and let me know the results.

Comment: Just reviewing this - The ISP eventually told me that their server was configured not to respond to direct client queries, only to other nameservers asking for information transfers - does `dig` query in a different way, like a nameserver would?

Comment: dig can do both regular questions (all types except AXFR) and zone transfers (type AXFR) but DNS operators usually restrict zone transfers to authorized slaves so you most probably want to use regular questions

Comment: FYI to fellow non-DNS admins: `dig`’s output is based on the [zone file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file). `;` starts a comment, and record columns are `name`, `ttl`, `record class`, `record type`, and [`record data`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-3.3). [BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/), of which `dig` is a part, documents [zone files](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.10.2/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2598276) elsewhere and omits this info from `dig`’s [man page](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.10.2/doc/arm/man.dig.html).

Comment: I'm getting much more info with `host`, like IPv6 records I couldn't get with `dig -6`: `dig @4.2.2.2 ehow.com;  host -v ehow.com 4.2.2.2`

Comment: @PabloA: `host` by default looks for A AAAA and MX records; see the man page under the `-t` option. `dig` by default looks only for A; since this host also has MX, `dig @4.2.2.2 ehow.com MX` to see them. It doesn't currently have AAAA but if or when it did `dig @4.2.2.2 ehow.com AAAA`.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using the non-FQDN hostname, the results can be different because `host` will use the search domains in `resolv.conf`, whereas `dig` does not by default.

You have to use the `+search` option if you want `dig` to use `resolv.conf` (or add it to `~/.digrc`).

For example:

```
$ host foo
foo.myfqdn.com has address 10.1.2.3

$ dig +short foo
# (no result)

$ dig +short +search foo
10.1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nslookup` command is included into Windows and BusyBox which is used on embedded devices like routers or TV boxes. This makes it more preferable for cross-platform scripting. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup

Examples of output for a comparison:

```
$ nslookup example.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
Name:   example.com
Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```

dig provides a response in a BIND zone format with many details:

```
$ dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41996
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        7147    IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 28 23:44:07 EET 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

The host command tries to give an explanation:

```
$ host example.com 
example.com has address 93.184.216.34
example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
example.com mail is handled by 0 .
```